# How to get form name value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to get the name of the form element itself using JSP? I searched google and did not find any examples which show how to get the name of the form value specified in the JSP file.

For example, I have the below form,

```html
<html>
    <form name="register" action="servregister" method="POST"
        onsubmit="return validate();">
    </form>
</html>
```

I would like to get the string "register" to a string variable in JSP. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to form name?

Comment: On a single servlet, i would like to have processing based on the form name using if clause.

Comment: It will be better using a MVC framework for that purpose, like JSF or Spring MVC.

Comment: @vinay You shouldn't do it based on the form name. You should probably do it based on the form `submit` element.

Comment: I'm new to java jsp. Sorry for being noob. Since each form name is different, thought whether it is possible to do it with the form name.

Comment: It is not about being new to a technology, the fact is that you could explain what you're trying to achieve and why in order to understand the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a `<form>` is not submitted with the request. Instead create a `hidden` input element which holds that information.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name of form" value="value" />
```

or possibly  the `submit` element

```
<input type="submit" name="distinguishing name" value="submit" />
```

Either of these in a form with be sent as a url-encoded parameter.

There is probably a better solution to what you are trying to do if you explain your goals.

---

Consider looking into different patterns for achieving your goals.

Comment: The hidden field may bring more maintenance problems, specially when having more than a single form in a single page.

Comment: Sorry to bother one more time, but the `submit` element name idea is even worse. What will happen if you have two *Save* submits in different pages? Will you need to add an additional parameter like the hidden to know what you're processing?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You aren't bothering :). Depends, are they posting to the same URL?

Comment: Since OP noted in comments that it will be a single servlet, then yes, it is the same action.

Comment: @Luiggi I can see why you mean the design is poor. One POST URL, but many possible handlers. POST isn't idempotent, so it's _alright_ to do this.

Comment: @Luiggi I think Tapestry also does.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, this answer serves my requirement.